# Java: How can a calculation on the data happen before the data is read in?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have two threads. One is EDT (using the swingUtilities.invokeLater) and the other is for calculation. I get the input from a mouse click handled in the EDT and then perform the calculation in the other. But I get the following output (the black numbers are in EDT, the red are in the other):

[image]

So it seems that the calculation occurs before I read the data from GUI. Could anyone explain why?

**Edit:** Some code:

```
  //in EDT
  public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) 
  {
      //get the position
      System.out.println(i + " " + j);---> black numbers
      played = true;        
  }

  //in thread 2
  public boolean valid (Move m) 
  {
      System.err.println(m.locX +" "+m.locY); ---> red numbers

      //use the position get in EDT

      System.out.println("finished");---> black 'finished'
  }
```

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your patience. I am learning to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.out and System.err are not "sequential" while printing to the output.

This simple code shows it:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.err.println(i);
        }
```

You'd be expecting the `out` to be executed before the `err`, right? It is, the problem is, it is just not PRINTED in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` can be assigned a lower priority than other types of output, and get printed after them, even if they are called before. It depends on what you are running your program on.

For example, in my setup, if I print something then throw an exception, the exception can come before the printed content.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any indication as to whether your operation is thread safe.  It seems that your red thread has the ability to attempt processing on black thread's output, and ends up reporting finished simply because it doesn't account for the black thread never having ran ( at least for this iteration )

Your code should have something that accounts for this case, or you set up a producer consumer model, or find yet another way to arbitrate events between the two threads.